# System.InvalidOperationException when trying use binding name as parameter in an azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, csx

follow this tutorial [chain-azure-functions-data-using-bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/chain-azure-functions-data-using-bindings/5-read-data-with-input-bindings-portal-lab), 
when using JavaScript it works, however created a new function app with .net as run time stack, added required cosmos db mappings, when sending GET request with query param like
https://azurefuncurl?code=abc&id=docs
appinsights reveals azure function/host wont start because of System.InvalidOperationException

tried going through official documentation: [azure-functions/configInput-Usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#input---usage), no luck

function.json

```
{
 "bindings": [
{
  "authLevel": "function",
  "name": "req",
  "type": "httpTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "methods": [
    "get",
    "post"
  ]
},
{
  "name": "$return",
  "type": "http",
  "direction": "out"
},
{
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "name": "bookmark",
  "databaseName": "func-io-learn-db",
  "collectionName": "Bookmarks",
  "connectionStringSetting": "chainazurefunctions_DOCUMENTDB",
  "id": "{id}",
  "partitionKey": "{id}",
  "direction": "in"
 }]
}
```

run.csx

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, dynamic bookmark)
{

log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

string name = req.Query["id"];

string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
name = name ?? data?.name;

return name != null
    ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
    : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

exception message:

`Error indexing method 'Functions.find-bookmark' Unable to resolve binding parameter 'id'. Binding expressions must map to either a value provided by the trigger or a property of the value the trigger is bound to, or must be a system binding expression (e.g. sys.randguid, sys.utcnow, etc.).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `{id}` with `{Query.id}`, have a look at the [csx sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-look-up-id-from-query-string-c-script).

Comment: Thank you, I did not look hard enough

Answer (score 1):

*for future references*
based on [Jerry Liu's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001807/system-invalidoperationexception-when-trying-use-binding-name-as-parameter-in-an/54002118#54002118)
,
I had to replace `id` with `{Query.id}` in function.json like note values in key id & partitionKey

```
{
  "type": "cosmosDB",
  "name": "bookmark",
  "databaseName": "func-io-learn-db",
  "collectionName": "Bookmarks",
  "connectionStringSetting": "chainazurefunctions_DOCUMENTDB",
  "id": "{Query.id}",
  "partitionKey": "{Query.id}",
  "direction": "in"
}
```

in run.csx

create a POCO model class & use it as a param in Run method, below is what entire run.csx looks like

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

public class Bookmark
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string id {get; set;}

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="url")]
    public string URL {get;set;}

}

public static HttpResponseMessage  Run(HttpRequest  req, ILogger log, Bookmark bookmark)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    if(bookmark == null)
    {        
        string id = req.Query["id"];
        log.LogInformation($"Bookmark item {id} not found");

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            Content = new StringContent($"{id} not found", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
    }
    else
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Found item {bookmark.URL}");
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bookmark), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        };
    }
}
```